# How to embed JasperReport sub-report into a jar

Tags: jasper-reports, embed

I have a jasper (master) report embed in a jar. The report is got from a java input stream. The jasper report is made by iReport 3.7.0

In this master report, there are a few sub-reports. At the moment I have to use

Subreport Expression : $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "\\SubReport.jasper"

Expression Class : java.lang.String

in the iReport to make it works. It means that I store the subReport.jasper in SUBREPORT_DIR folder.

My question is, how to embed these sub-reports in the jar like the master report? And what should fill in the "Default Value Expression"? (if it is needed)

The closest question and answer so far I have seen is in here

[How to load subreport resources with Jasper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825726/how-to-load-subreport-resources-with-jasper)

However the answer is not sufficient to me for master report compile. There is an error message saying missing sub-report when compile (and this is why I think the Default Value Expression may be needed?)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for example:
i have report and subreport, located in some *.jar file. to invoke subreport i set subreport expression

```
getClass().getResource("/path/to/my/report/in/a/jar/subreport.jasper").openStream()
```

and choose subreport expression class `java.io.InputStream`

it is working!

Answer (score 0):

I've described one possible solution in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598958/jasper-sub-report-error/10600015#10600015) in another question. Question is not identical, but the solution solves this problem also.

That solution uses spring, but replacing spring specific parts (FileSystemResourceLoader) with  `Class.getResourceAsStream()` should not be too big of a problem.